# Python passing arguments to already running executables

Tags: python, command-line, executable

I'm trying to pass an argument at an executable program launched from the command line. The passed argument is not required at the initial executable execution but it is asked after some computations are done. The process remains in pending condition until the required argument is passed from command line.
After the insertion of such parameter the program ends its execution. I need to automate the overall process. 
Is there anyone who can help me ?

Any possible suggestions are welcome

Michele

Answer (score 0):

You need interaction, a way to start a process, and then monitor its output and be able to pass input to the process..

Python has this, it is called [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). There are many examples of similar questions and answers here on StackOverflow.

For example:

- [Running an interactive command from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457931/running-an-interactive-command-from-within-python)
- [Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument)

And [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python%20interact%20with%20subprocess).