# Python subprocess stdout iterator always blocks

Tags: python

I want to capture the output while printing it, but I'm blocking forever without reading even a single line. **What's going on?** I'm using Python2.

Generator script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import random
import time

while True:
    print(random.random())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Sample generator output:

```
$ ./generator.py 
0.334835137212
0.896609571236
0.833267988558
0.55456332113
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
```

Reader script:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['./generator.py']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in p.stdout:
    print(line)
    print('Looping')

p.wait()
```

I've also tried:

```
import subprocess
import sys

cmd = ['./generator.py']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    print(line)

    print('Looping')

p.wait()
```

...and:

```
import sys
import subprocess
import select
import time

cmd = ['./generator.py']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

s = select.poll()
s.register(p.stdout, select.POLLIN)

while True:
    if s.poll(1):
        line = p.stdout.read()
    else:
        p.poll()
        if p.returncode is not None:
            break

    print('Looping')
    time.sleep(1)

p.wait()
```

Comment: you should use `p.communicate()`, not use stdout directly. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin ...

Comment: How are you executing these scripts?  Reading from `stdout` is not the usual attempt at inter-process communication.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Using communicate() is useless with a long-running process. You won't be able to print it until the end.

Comment: @Prune IPC is not a requirement. All I need to do is print the output iteratively while capturing it.

Comment: This is missing a `sys.stdout.flush()` (or `flush=True`) in the generator. Otherwise, you'll have to wait until it fills the output buffer, which --given the `sleep(1)`-- might take a while.

Comment: @dhke It doesn't matter. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @DustinOprea Repeat: "This is missing a sys.stdout.flush() (or flush=True) **in the generator**". Flushing in the consumer won't help you much, when the buffering happens in the generator script. Try `print(random.random(), flush=True)`

Comment: you are right... maybe take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880190/interactive-input-output-using-python

Comment: @DustinOprea Then either (given you call `print()` as a function) `from __future__ import print_function` at the very top or use `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print(random.random())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dhke mentioned, one of the issues is implicit output-buffering in the producer. If you have the ability to change the producer, and you're willing to, *and* the production is done by calls to the print-function then just add "flush=True" as an argument to the `print` function. You can also fall-back to doing a `sys.stdout.flush()` at key points in the producer.

The second problem appears to be iterating over `sys.stdout`. This never seems to work for a long-running process. The second and third methods

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with a similar problem. This is the workaround im currently using to prevent buffering.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['stdbuf', '-o0'] + cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The disadvantage of this methood is that it relys on an external Linux command to solve the problem. Have a look in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307620/iterate-over-stdout-of-subprocess) for a different and native python approach to get rid of the PIPE buffering. Many thanks to @9000 for suggesting both solutions to me.