# Iterate over stdout of subprocess

Tags: python

I want to iterate over stdout of a subprocess while the subprocess is still running. My current approach looks like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['long_running_command'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
    # do some stuff
    print(line.rstrip())
```

At the moment the code in the for-loop will only be executed when the subprocess is finished. Is it possible to iterate over stdout of a runnnig subprocess and if yes how is it done? I know there are many existing threads with similar questions. However none of the provided answers seem to work for me.

Comment: This looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6414278/1832539) answer. Did you see that yet?

Comment: How much data does the subprocess produce? Normal output buffering would send every line at best, not every character. Buffering [can be prevented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40453613/223424).

Comment: take a peak at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running

Comment: @idjaw: thats pretty much what I did. Nevertheless i tried the answer the exact same way as it was suggested. I did not work.

Comment: @9000: It produces a few lines of text. The solution you suggested worked. Thanks. However is there a way that does this without relying on external commands?

Comment: @Jacobr365: I saw that already, but thanks.

Comment: @RobertMoskal: I know there are a lot of similar threads. However, I did not find a satisfying answer.

Comment: @f1nan: I suppose it's the OS mechanics, not Python's. You can consider [opening an explicit pipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkfifo), set it unbuffered, and pass it as `stdout` to the process. This won't depend on an external program.

Comment: @9000: Thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: @9000: That doesn’t do anything: only the file descriptor is preserved across `exec`, and it doesn’t do the buffering anyway.