# subprocess.Popen to interact with a CLI prompt

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, command-line-interface, popen

I am trying to write and read from a CLI program using `subprocess.Popen`.

So every time you issue a command to the CLI it prints something, and that something is what I want to read. I will try to explain what I want do to with a concrete example so everybody can try.

Thus, instead of using `my real program` I will use `ipython` for which the problem holds:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ipython'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(input="5+5")
```

If you use `Popen.communicate(input=command)` you get at `stdout` exactly all the text that `ipython` would print in the terminal if I would have executed it directly from the `shell`.

**What I want to do:**

Instead of using `communicate`. I want to be able to send individual commands and read the immediate output. For example I would like to do:

```
p.stdin.write("5+5")
out1 = p.stdout.read()

p.stdin.write("5*10")
out2 = p.stdout.read()
```

So `out1` should be 5 and `out2` should be 50.

**Problem:**

You can not read the `stdout` until you close `stdin`.

How do you do that ? I can't use `read(n)` or `readline()` since in my real application I do not know the length of the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Interactive input/output using python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880190/interactive-input-output-using-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to open a bash session with Python and keep communicating with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947625/how-to-open-a-bash-session-with-python-and-keep-communicating-with-it)

Comment: @John1024 thanks. It is not the same exactly but maybe it does work. I will give them a try. EDIT: I tried and does not work, somehow does solutions allow you to read without blocking but there is nothing at the output until you do `p.stdin.close()`.

Comment: The other question showed a number of possible solutions.  Proper form on StackExchange would be to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47948512/edit) your question above precisely what you tried and precisely how it didn't work.  That would (a) demonstrate that this is not a duplicate, and (b) give people here something to work with.

Comment: I added a new version with an example where the problem happens.

Comment: You can't `read()` the stdout, as that will read to the end of the file. But you can read bytes or lines, e.g. using `.readline()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

Comment: I tried that but I do not know the length of the output. But now that you say it. Would it work if I combine `readline()` and the non-blocking solution? I read lines until I get the exception.

Comment: Actually that does not work. In the case of the `ipython` you can read line by line. However with my `other-prompt` when you do a `readline()` there is  nothing to read apparently. So the program just puts something to `stdout` when you really close `stdin`. But then how is it possible that if you run that program with the normal shell, then its able to print outputs when you "hit" return.

Answer (score 2):

With some minor modifications, I was able to make the approach from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880190/interactive-input-output-using-python) work.

Using Python3:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> 
>>> fw = open("tmpout", "wb")
>>> fr = open("tmpout", "r")
>>> p = Popen("ipython", stdin=PIPE, stdout=fw, stderr=fw, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
>>> header = fr.read()
>>> p.stdin.write("100*50\n")
7
>>> fr.read()
'\nIn [1]: Out[1]: \n5000\n'
>>> p.stdin.write("2/3.\n")
5
>>> fr.read()
'\nIn [2]: Out[2]: \n0.6667\n'
```

As you can see, it works interactively.

A trick is that, under Py3, `bufsize=1` makes I/O line-buffered *only if* `universal_newlines=True`.

Comment: what about python2?

Comment: @edgarstack The same solution works for me on Python2 with or without the `universal_newlines=True` option.  (If you have a choice, use Py3:  Py2 is approaching [end-of-life.](https://pythonclock.org/))

Answer (score 0):

Calling `communicate()` blocks until the process exits, which is not what you want. You need to read from `p.stdout` and write to `p.stdin`.

Alternatively, you might find the [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io) module useful.

Comment: Thats what I said somehow. With `communicate` it works because it kills makes the process terminate somehow. But with `p.read()` which is what I want it does not work.

Comment: @edgarstack: You should edit your question to show your code. You might be deadlocking with the other process.

Comment: The other process I can not show it because its a big program. But my code is basically that. 1) `p=popen`, 2) `p.stdin.write(command)`, 3) `p.stdout.read()`.