# How to supress the "stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device" error

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

**Problem**

Basically I've have working with a Python script that emulate a real terminal. So, I was trying some tools for Linux, and when I try to use some tools the STDOUT comes with:

> stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device" message error

**Question**

Is possible to suppress this error message without the *.replace()*?

**Script**

```
import subprocess
import os

f = open('output.txt', 'w')
proc = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=f, shell=True)
while True:
    command = input('Type:')
    if command == "cls":
        open('output.txt', 'w').close()
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    else:
        command = command.encode('utf-8') + b'\n'
        proc.stdin.write(command)
        proc.stdin.flush()
        with open('output.txt', 'r+') as ff:
            print(ff.read())
```

**Error example**

$ python3 script.py

Type: msfconsole

*wait a few seconds for load the banner

Type: banner

```
   =[ metasploit v6.0.15-dev                          ]
```

- -- --=[ 2071 exploits - 1123 auxiliary - 352 post       ]
- -- --=[ 592 payloads - 45 encoders - 10 nops            ]
- -- --=[ 7 evasion                                       ]

Metasploit tip: Use the edit command to open the currently active module in your editor

stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

msf6>

Type:

Comment: Does the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880190/interactive-input-output-using-python) solve your problem?

Comment: That question/answer aren't pertinent.

Comment: @ThomasDickey - how so?

Comment: To me it's obvious that the "invalid IOCTL" pertains to the `stdout=f,`, which using a pipe as the answers suggest will do away with.

Answer (score -1):

You can add other exceptions, like you did for `cls` :

```
    elif command == "stty" or command == "...":
        os.system(command)
```