# How to use subprocess for completing complex interactive shell-scripts

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

For example, lets say I want to access a Postgresql database in the shell and apply the command `select *;`. This would require me to run:

1. `psql -U postgres`
2. <insert the password> (optional)
3. `select *;`

and ideally get the the intermediate output after each step. This is only a toy example, for doing this `sqlalchemy` would be a good pick, but still it should be possible through pythons `subprocess` module.

What I have tried based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880190/interactive-input-output-using-python):

```
    start = f"psql -U postgres"
    fw = open("tmpout.txt", "wb")
    fr = open("tmpout.txt", "r")
    p = subprocess.Popen(start, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=fw, stderr=fw, bufsize=1, 
        shell=True)
    p.stdin.write(bytes("select *;", 'utf-8'))
    out = fr.read() # Here i would expect the result of the select, but it doesn't terminate..
```

Comment: The Python `pexpect` module might be an easier way to be interactive with other processes... https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: It doesn't terminate because subprocess doesn't terminate. You should read it line by line
look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line