# Why is subprocess.run entering a newline for input?

Tags: python, subprocess

This is a sample code snippet which reproduces the issue I'm facing:

```
import subprocess

ctb_path = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Cold Turkey\\Cold Turkey Blocker.exe\""
exception = input("Enter the exception phrase: ")
subprocess.run(f'{ctb_path} -add Distractions -exception \"*{exception}*\"', check=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
choice = input("Enter your choice between 1 & 2: ")
```

Here, I'm not asked for an input because a newline has been accepted instead and successfully exited the program. What are the possible reasons this may occur? How can it be fixed?

[image: Output of the above code]

Refer [this](https://getcoldturkey.com/support/user-guide/#part-commands) for Cold Turkey Blocker's User Guide.

Comment: `input()` is to interact with your python code, not a program that you would have run inside it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880190/interactive-input-output-using-python

Comment: I just tried it on linux with `['echo', 'test']` as the command, and it worked like it should.  Are you putting the command in as a single string like that?  That gets an error for me.  Can you reproduce the error with a trivial command so that you can show us?

Comment: I intend to first use subprocess to run a command in cmd. After that's completed, the python program should ask me for input. But it takes a newline as the input, which is returned by the subprocess. That's the issue. I'll add a screenshot showing the output.

Comment: Yes @azro that's what I intend to do, interact with my python program AFTER subprocess runs the cmd command.