# Kattis Issue, Texture Analysis. Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm having issues with debugging the texture analysis on Kattis. I'm able to finish every test case i can imagine but yet the last test case fails.
Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the last test case to fail?

[Link to the kattis problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/textureanalysis)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedWriter dc = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

    int numOfLines = 1;

    for (;;) {
        String inputLine = sc.readLine();
        if (inputLine.equals("END"))
            break;
        else if (!inputLine.contains(".")) {
            dc.write(numOfLines++ + " EVEN\n");
        } else {
            //Next two lines creates an array out of the characters in a single line
            String[] tempArray = inputLine.split("");
            ArrayList<String> charArray = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tempArray));
            //Next block of code finds all elements where an asterix has been found and puts them in the allIndexes array
            //If the code is even, the elements will for example be on 0, 2, 4, 6
            //If the code is uneven, the elements will for example be on 0, 1, 5, 8
            String str = "*";
            List<Integer> allIndexes =
                    IntStream.range(0, charArray.size()).boxed()
                            .filter(j -> charArray.get(j).equals(str))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

            ArrayList<Integer> duplicateList = new ArrayList<>();
            //For-loop, is used to normalize numbers
            //An even array of 0,2,4,6 turns into 2,2,2,2
            //An uneven array of 0,2,6,8 turns into 2,4,2,2
            //This means we can easily see where the uneven number is
            for (int j = 0; j < allIndexes.size(); j++) {
                if(j < allIndexes.size() - 1)
                    duplicateList.add(allIndexes.get(j + 1) - allIndexes.get(j));
            }
            Boolean isArrayUneven = false;
            //Here we check for uneven numbers in the array
            //If one is found then isArrayUneven turns true.
            for (int i = 1; i < duplicateList.size();i++) {
                if (duplicateList.get(0) != duplicateList.get(i)) {
                    isArrayUneven = true;
                }
            }
            if (isArrayUneven ==true ) {
                dc.write(numOfLines++ + " NOT EVEN" + "\n");
            }
            else{
                dc.write(numOfLines++ + " EVEN" + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
    dc.close();
    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the solution seems a bit overengineered to me, I coded a working solution which was accepted by Kattis, then compared it against yours with a script on a variety of tests and couldn't find any differences. There's a slight chance it's a Java version behavior or platform issue of some sort, but I can't imagine what. Here's my solution and testing script in case it helps:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class TextureAnalysis {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        var sc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        var dc = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

        for (int i = 1;; i++) {
            String s = sc.readLine();
    
            if (s.equals("END")) {
                break;
            }

            var a = s.split("\\*", -1);
            boolean allSameLength = true;

            for (int j = 2; j < a.length - 1; j++) {
                if (a[j].length() != a[1].length()) {
                    allSameLength = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            dc.write(i + (allSameLength ? " EVEN\n" : " NOT EVEN\n"));
        }

        dc.close();
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Testing script:

```py
import random
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def start(cmd):
    return Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)


def read(process):
    return process.stdout.read().decode("utf-8")


def write(process, s):
    process.stdin.write(f"{s}\n".encode("utf-8"))
    process.stdin.flush()


def terminate(process):
    process.stdin.close()
    process.terminate()
    process.wait(timeout=0.2)


def main():
    # even tests
    for i in range(100):
        good = start(["java", "TextureAnalysis"])
        bad = start(["java", "TextureAnalysisBad"])

        for j in range(100):
            chunk = "*".join(["." * i for _ in range(j)])
            test = "*" + chunk + "*"
            write(good, test)
            write(bad, test)

        write(good, "END")
        write(bad, "END")
        g = read(good)
        b = read(bad)

        if g != b:
            print("FAIL:", test)
            sys.exit(0)

    # random tests, mostly uneven
    for _ in range(1000000):
        good = start(["java", "TextureAnalysis"])
        bad = start(["java", "TextureAnalysisBad"])
        
        for j in range(100):
            chunk = "".join(
                [random.choice(".*") for _ in range(random.randint(10, 150))]
            )
            test = "*" + chunk + "*"
            write(good, test)
            write(bad, test)
        
        write(good, "END")
        write(bad, "END")
        g = read(good)
        b = read(bad)
        
        if g != b:
            print("FAIL:", test)
            sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880190/interactive-input-output-using-python/52544846#52544846) for subprocess code)