# Docker: input from web UI user to Docker run Python interpreter

Tags: python, docker, sandbox

I am trying to make a web application that automatically grades python code supplied by programming students. I have planned to interpret the code in a Docker instance as a means of sandboxing but now I've hit a problem. What if a student writes input("...") in their code? This will leave the python interpreter inside the Docker waiting for additional input. The docker container will eventually get killed if it doesn't finish within some time but I would actually want to offer the oppurtunity for the students to give input to their programs. I know I could start the Docker in interactive mode but then the problem is:

How could docker let my webservice know that the web UI user should be prompted for input?

Comment: CMD yes | run_python ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you mean...

Comment: Have you already checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911788/docker-how-to-send-input-to-a-program-via-the-api

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [wetty](https://github.com/krishnasrinivas/wetty) project. You could provide an actual bash (or other shell, iptyhon?) prompt where they could interact with the prompt from the convenience of their web browser.

There are several pre-made dockerfiles to go by as examples:
https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=wetty