# stdin for Interactive command from python

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, interactive

I'm trying to integrate an interactive lua shell into my python GUI with a similar approach as described here: [Running an interactive command from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457931/running-an-interactive-command-from-within-python) Target platform for now is windows. I want to be able to feed the lua interpreter line by line.

```
import subprocess
import os
from queue import Queue
from queue import Empty
from threading import Thread
import time


def enqueue_output(out, queue):
  for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
    queue.put(line)
  out.close()

lua = '''\
-- comment
print("A")
test = 0
test2 = 1
os.exit()'''

command = os.path.join('lua', 'bin', 'lua.exe')
process = (subprocess.Popen(command + ' -i', shell=True,
           stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=os.getcwd(), bufsize=1,
           universal_newlines=True))

outQueue = Queue()
errQueue = Queue()

outThread = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(process.stdout, outQueue))
errThread = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(process.stderr, errQueue))

outThread.daemon = True
errThread.daemon = True

outThread.start()
errThread.start()

script = lua.split('\n')
time.sleep(.2)
for line in script:
  while True:
    try:
      rep = outQueue.get(timeout=.2)
    except Empty:
      break
    else:  # got line
      print(rep)
  process.stdin.write(line)
```

The only output I receive is the very first line of the lua.exe shell. It seems that the writing to stdin doesn't actually take place. Is there anything I miss?

Running an external lua file with the -i switch actually works and yields the expected output which makes me think the issue is connected to the stdin.

I experimented a bit in python interactive mode using the python shell trying something similar to the solution featuring a file for the stdout here: [Interactive input/output using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880190/interactive-input-output-using-python). However, this only wrote the output to the file once I stopped the python shell, which also seems like the stdin gets stalled somewhere and is only actually transmitted, once I quit the shell. Any ideas what goes wrong here?

Comment: Bidirectional popen is problematic in general (read up about deadlocks that can occur).  I suggest you use Lua as a library instead of invoking the executable.

Comment: Does it work if you pass all at once `out, err = process.communicate(lua)`? Unrelated: you could use triple quotes for multiline strings or rely on implicit concatenation: `'a' 'b'` -- is a single string `'ab'` i.e., don't use backslashes here

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm using the same executable on a similar task for a different purpose, that's why I'd like to use one single executable. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, passing it all at once works. Unfortunately that is not an option since I want to support breakpoints. This is supposed to be a an environment to develop and test scripts. Thanks for the hints about the string, changed it.

Comment: If it works all at once then it might be a buffering issue: add `process.stdin.flush()`, add `\n` at the end of each line. You should consume `errQueue` too or use a single queue.

Comment: Great it works now, the error I made was the missing \n - I forgot that the split removes it - I actually had the flush at some point but the \n was missing. Do you want to post this as an answer so I can award it to you?

Comment: no need. If you found a solution; you could [post it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)