# How can I use 'SetText' in command prompt?

Tags: python, pywinauto

[1]
The code is:

```
import pywinauto
app = pywinauto.Application()
mainApplication = app.window_(title_re = ".*Environment.*")
mainApplication.Minimize()
mainApplication.Edit.SetText("test", with_spaces=True)
mainApplication.Edit.SetText("{ENTER}")
```

[2]
The output is:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 239, in __getattr__
    ctrls = _resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 754, in _resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
WindowNotFoundError
```

Note: If I use 'TypeKeys' method I do not encounter any problem, but I want to write in an app. even if focus is not set on it.

Comment: What is the application? `cmd.exe`? BTW, `with_spaces=True` is not a param of `SetText`. The code is incorrect.

Comment: [1] yes. cmd exe. [2] 'with_spaces=True' it was a reminescence of 'typekeys'. I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately cmd.exe has no any controls inside the window. So you cannot send `WM_SETTEXT` message to it. That's why `SetText` isn't working. And it will never work for cmd.exe because GUI automation tool is for GUI, not for command line.

Generally you can interact with cmd.exe process through pipes using standard module `subprocess` (class `Popen`).

You can try the following:

1. run `cmd.exe` through `Popen`,
2. `Connect(path='cmd.exe')` using pywinauto,
3. call `app.Window_().Minimize()`,
4. send keys using `p.stdin.write(someInput)` where `p` is a `Popen` object.

When you're using pipes, there are some pitfalls with potential dead lock of input and output streams.
Here is one method to workaround some issues: [Running an interactive command from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457931/running-an-interactive-command-from-within-python)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. I found a way to writetext to inactive cmmand prompt. import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
handle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, u'Administrator:  Environment')
print handle
for text in "test":
        win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_CHAR, ord(text), 0)

Comment: Great finding! We will implement `SendChars` method in pywinauto using `WM_CHAR`. Is there some way to retrieve console text using some message? If you could find it, please let us know.