# Passing Arguments to subprocess.Popen in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, subprocess

I have the following code. It connects to a Service Now Instance. Fetches Incident for particular server. The Incident has details for Printer Creation. 
ip is in record['user_input'],printer name is in record['u_string_full_utf8_1']. What I would like to achieve is pass these as arguments to powershell so that it can run the Printer Create script. The arguments passed in the below code works. But I am not sure how to pass arguments in the middle of it.

```
import pysnow
import subprocess
import os

# Create client object
s = pysnow.Client(instance='instance', user='admin', password='password')

# Get all incidents
r = s.query('incident', query={'cmdb_ci':'a28cba7a4fb4030028f7fd218110c7f5'})

# order by 'created_on' descending, then iterate over the result and print out number
for record in r.get_multiple(order_by=['-created_on']):
    print(record['cmdb_ci'])

psxmlgen = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe',
                            "Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVER01 -FilePath 'C:\Users\testuser\Documents\Scripts\PrinterCreate.ps1' -ArgumentList '10.2.3.2','PS Driver for Universal Print','TESTPRINTER' -Credential $cred"], cwd=os.getcwd())
result = psxmlgen.wait()
```

I checked the existing resources but was unable to figure out how to pass it in the middle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Using Python2.7

Comment: You may want to prefix an 'r' in the second argument to the popen.

Comment: Got it to work. I agree there should be r but its working without it and I think if ain't broke then don't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with the following:

```
psxmlgen = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe',
                            "Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -FilePath 'C:\Users\smehta30\Documents\Scripts\PrinterCreate.ps1' -ArgumentList "+record['user_input']+",'PS Driver for Universal Print',"+record['u_string_full_utf8_1']+" -Credential $cred"], cwd=os.getcwd())
```

Comment: That works, but it's dangerous unless you trust your inputs -- values in `record` containing literal double-quotes could exit their escaping to perform injection attacks, providing arbitrary powershell code.

Comment: (I could tell you how to avoid the same problem in bash, but unfortunately, with PowerShell I'm no help; that said, the same problem clearly exists in both places).

Comment: (As an aside -- the current working directory of the parent should be default for the child; does `cwd=` really change anything?)

Comment: First of all thanks for the edit. My bad. 

I am currently working for a prototype to display Servicenow automated printer creation queries. It is in very early stage. 

I need to learn how to avoid injection. Can you please provide the Bash code. Maybe I can implement something through here.

Hmm would have to limit Input at Request creation end. Will look into it.

Comment: so, in bash, you'd write `subprocess.Popen(['sh', '-c', 'code using "$1" and "$2"', '_', record['user_input'], record['u_string_full_utf8_1'])` -- that way the values are passed to the shell interpreter out-of-band from code and substituted later.

Comment: (Frankly, if there isn't already a StackOverflow question on how to safely pass variables to PowerShell from Python, it's probably worth asking).

Answer (score 0):

There are two similar questions which you can reference. Popen gives you access to stdin of a interactive process. You may want to refer to

[Running an interactive command from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457931/running-an-interactive-command-from-within-python)

[Running powershell script within python script, how to make python print the powershell output while it is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944895/running-powershell-script-within-python-script-how-to-make-python-print-the-pow)

both may help. I am not sure if powershell exposes it's stdin and stdout as normal native processes in windows.