# Accessing matlab terminal from python

Tags: python, matlab, subprocess

How do I call commands in a Matlab terminal when it's opened through Python? I call this:

```
subprocess.call(["matlab", "-nosplash", "-nodesktop", "-r"], shell=True)
```

which opens a terminal window. But how can I send new commands in there? I tried simply adding them to the current call, but they don't execute.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567371/wrapping-an-interactive-command-line-application-in-a-python-script, and maybe also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457931/running-an-interactive-command-from-within-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
subprocess.call(["matlab", "-nosplash", "-nodesktop", "-r", "command1;command2;"], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stout=subprocess.PIPE)
```