# python: string as stdin to subcommand

Tags: python, shell

I have a python script in which I need to invoke a shell command.  The shell command can accept its input from  either a file or stdin.

In my script, the input is stored in a variable.  What is the proper way to invoke the command?  If it matters, the shell command produces no output.

I know I could write the variable's content into a file and invoke the command with the file as argument but that seems inelegant.  Surely, there's a better way.

Can someone tell me what it is?  Thanks.

Comment: I think this answer will be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8475367/1374493

Comment: You should have been able to Google this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping an interactive command line application in a python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567371/wrapping-an-interactive-command-line-application-in-a-python-script)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i write to a python subprocess' stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["Mycommand", "with", "arguments"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process.communicate("My text")
```

Comment: "Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process." (From https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: @palvarez89 Good call.  I fixed it.

Comment: `communicate()` is a one-off method. To do that repeatedly, I copied some code from its implementation that handled `stdin` in a separate thread.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev My answer *did* use `process.stdin.write`, but as palvarez89 mentioned, that is not the preferred way.  The OP mentioned trying to `write the variable's content into a file and invoke the command with the file as argument`.  If it were a problem to use a one-off method, that would not have been suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument)

For python 3.5+ (3.6+ for encoding), you can use input:

```
from subprocess import check_output   
output = check_output(["cat","-b"],
        input="-foo\n-bar\n-foobar", encoding='ascii')
print(output)
```

[image: example]